# Storing tokens with OAuth 2.0 in Angular

Tags: angularjs, oauth, google-calendar-api

I have an app which displays Google Calendar data, but it requires an initial login. I know it's possible to store tokens using OAuth 2.0, but I'm not sure how to go about doing it. Here is my code below. I'd like for the webpage to display the a calendar using JSON data from a google calendar without login.

Controller

```
angular.module('demo', ["googleApi"])
.config(function(googleLoginProvider) {
    googleLoginProvider.configure({
        clientId: '239511214798.apps.googleusercontent.com',
        scopes: ["https://www.googleapis.com/auth/userinfo.email", "https://www.googleapis.com/auth/calendar", "https://www.googleapis.com/auth/plus.login"]
    });
})
.controller('DemoCtrl', ['$scope', 'googleLogin', 'googleCalendar', 'googlePlus', function ($scope, googleLogin, googleCalendar, googlePlus) {

    $scope.login = function () {
        googleLogin.login();
    };

    $scope.$on("googlePlus:loaded", function() {
      googlePlus.getCurrentUser().then(function(user) {
        $scope.currentUser = user;
      });
    })
    $scope.currentUser = googleLogin.currentUser;

    $scope.loadEvents = function() {
        this.calendarItems = googleCalendar.listEvents({calendarId: this.selectedCalendar.id});
    }

    $scope.loadCalendars = function() {
        $scope.calendars = googleCalendar.listCalendars();
    }

}]);
```

googleAPi

```
angular.module('googleApi', [])
.value('version', '0.1')

.service("googleApiBuilder", function($q) {
    this.loadClientCallbacks = [];

    this.build = function(requestBuilder, responseTransformer) {
        return function(args) {
            var deferred = $q.defer();
            var response;
            request = requestBuilder(args);
            request.execute(function(resp, raw) {
                if(resp.error) {
                    deferred.reject(resp.error);
                } else {
                    response = responseTransformer ? responseTransformer(resp) : resp;
                    deferred.resolve(response);
                }

            });
            return deferred.promise;

        }
    };

    this.afterClientLoaded = function(callback) {
        this.loadClientCallbacks.push(callback);
    };

    this.runClientLoadedCallbacks = function() {
        for(var i=0; i < this.loadClientCallbacks.length; i++) {
            this.loadClientCallbacks[i]();
        }
    };
})

.provider('googleLogin', function() {

    this.configure = function(conf) {
        this.config = conf;
    };

    this.$get = function ($q, googleApiBuilder, $rootScope) {
        var config = this.config;
        var deferred = $q.defer();
        return {
            login: function () {
                gapi.auth.authorize({ client_id: config.clientId, scope: config.scopes, immediate: false}, this.handleAuthResult);

                return deferred.promise;
            },

            handleClientLoad: function () {
                gapi.auth.init(function () { });
                window.setTimeout(checkAuth, 1);
            },

            checkAuth: function() {
                gapi.auth.authorize({ client_id: config.clientId, scope: config.scopes, immediate: true }, this.handleAuthResult );
            },

            handleAuthResult: function(authResult) {
                if (authResult && !authResult.error) {
                    var data = {};
                    $rootScope.$broadcast("google:authenticated", authResult);
                    googleApiBuilder.runClientLoadedCallbacks();
                    deferred.resolve(data);
                } else {
                    deferred.reject(authResult.error);
                }
            },
        }
    };


})

.service("googleCalendar", function(googleApiBuilder, $rootScope) {

    var self = this;
    var itemExtractor = function(resp) { return resp.items; };

    googleApiBuilder.afterClientLoaded(function() {
        gapi.client.load('calendar', 'v3', function() {

            self.listEvents = googleApiBuilder.build(gapi.client.calendar.events.list, itemExtractor);
            self.listCalendars = googleApiBuilder.build(gapi.client.calendar.calendarList.list, itemExtractor);
            self.createEvent = googleApiBuilder.build(gapi.client.calendar.events.insert);

            $rootScope.$broadcast("googleCalendar:loaded")
        });

    });

})

    .service("googlePlus", function(googleApiBuilder, $rootScope) {

            var self = this;
            var itemExtractor = function(resp) { return resp.items; };

            googleApiBuilder.afterClientLoaded(function() {
                    gapi.client.load('plus', 'v1', function() {
                        self.getPeople = googleApiBuilder.build(gapi.client.plus.people.get);
                        self.getCurrentUser = function() {
                            return self.getPeople({userId: "me"});
                        }
                        $rootScope.$broadcast("googlePlus:loaded")
                    });

            });

    })
```

Comment: Are you asking how to use a hard-coded auth token? Or do you want to show a calendar without having a user login? If it's the latter I don't see how there could be any way to do that unfortunately.

Comment: From the research I've done, hard-coding won't work with the OAuth system. My understanding is there is a way to store tokens without hard coding.

Comment: It depends on what you mean. Storing tokens definitely works in OAuth 2.0 but OAuth 1.0 had a token that had to be generated on every request. Is that what you mean?

Comment: That is. So I definitely need OAuth 2.0 then.

Comment: Can you update your question to clarify a bit what exactly you want to accomplish? I think that may make it easier to help you.

Comment: I've made the update, thanks.

Answer (score 0):

What you will want to do is after the result comes back you will want to save it off to localStorage or a cookie and then use that in the future if it exists.

Essentially you will need to update your handleAuthResult to store the result from the Google API:

```
        handleAuthResult: function (authResult) {
            if (authResult && !authResult.error) {
                var data = {};
                $rootScope.$broadcast("google:authenticated", authResult);
                googleApiBuilder.runClientLoadedCallbacks();

                // here you will store the auth_token
                window.localStorage.setItem('auth_token', authResult.token /*I don't know what this response looks like, but it should be similar to this*/ );

                deferred.resolve(data);
            } else {
                deferred.reject(authResult.error);
            }
        },
```

[Live Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/TwoToneBytes/rs0g61bo/3/)

Comment: thanks. Maybe what I'm hoping to accomplish isn't possible. I'm hoping to avoid the login altogether so that I can access data from a private Google calendar and use the JSON data sent back to build a calendar on the site.

Comment: Ahh okay yeah I can't imagine that would be possible. Otherwise why else would they require login? :)